# Adding images to android project - eclipse

Tags: android

i am trying to add an image in my android app.  I am using html. I have my photos in the res/drawable folder.  I use the code img src= but i just get a question mark over the image. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `I use the code img src=` What? Post your code.

Comment: Img src='appname/res/drawable-mdpi/image.png'

Comment: Where is this code? What are you using to make your app?

Comment: The code Is in my main index. Html file. I use html to write my apps. I am using eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
<img src="file:///android_res/drawable/image.png" />
```

You do not need to put the qualifier for the drawable in the SRC attribute.